# JMS-MQ Test Plan Point to Point - JMETER

Tags: jmeter, websphere-mq

Buen día a todos!

Me encuentro realizando un plan en JMeter para las famosas pruebas de estrés, si bien ya he realizado pruebas hacia colas de Weblogic, tengo un problema con las de tipo MQ, nunca lo había hecho.

He realizado tal cual el procedimiento de distintos tutoriales, pero no he tenido éxito. Estos son algunos de los tutoriales de los que me he basado:

1. [jMeter - JMS Test Plan](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_jms_test_plan.htm)
2. [10.2 Adición de muestra de punto a punto JMS](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html)
3. Entre otros.

La configuración que tengo es la siguiente:

en las propiedades del JNDI tengo los datos:

- queueManager.
- hostName.
- port.
- transportType.
- queue.QL.QUEUE.IN

[image: Configuración del Plan]

[image: Configuración del Plan]

Este es el error que me arroja al momento de lanzar la petición:

> Response message: javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX

[image: Error]

Si alguien ha realizado este tipo de configuraciones en JMeter y pudiera ayudarme, de verdad gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de una ardua investigación en conjunto, se encontró la siguiente solución.

1. Generar una carpeta exclusiva para los siguientes Jars

   Ej: C:\example\apache-jmeter-4.0\lib\ibmmq

   - com.ibm.mq.jar
   - org.springframework.beans.jar
   - org.springframework.jms.jar
   - javax.jms.jar
   - jmeter-jms-skip-jndi-0.0.1.jar
   - spring-core.jar
2. Editar el archivo user.properties, colocando la siguiente línea: user.classpath=../lib/ibmmq;

[image: ejemplo]

3. Reiniciar JMeter,  en la consola de inicio deberá mostrarse la lectura de la ruta donde se encuentran los jars:

[image: Ejemplo]

En la plantilla de JMS point to point:

- En el campo QueueConnectionFactory colocar **CONNECTION_FACTORY**
- De igual forma el Initial Context Factory se debe colocar **com.elega9t.jmeter.jms.InitialContextFactory**
- Para el nombre de la cola (JNDI Name Request Queue), siempre se debe especificar **QUEUE_**[Nombre de la cola].

***Nota***: para este tipo de conexiones son lo establecido por default.

Si llegase a marcar errores de falta de librerías, se debe cargar el jar **activemqall ** para cargar todas las lib de MQ.